# Monitoring CPU and MEM of embedded system with Jenkins

Tags: testing, memory, jenkins, embedded, cpu

I need to somehow monitor the CPU and MEM usage of an embedded system during automated system tests using Jenkins.

As of now Jenkins is flashing my target with the newest build and afterwards running some tests. The system is running arm linux so i would be able make a script to poll the info through ssh during the tests.

My question is if there already is a tool that provides this functionality - if not how would i make jenkins process a file and provide a graph of the cpu and memory info during these tests?

Answer (score 0):

Would this plugin suit your needs?

[Monitoring plugin: Monitoring of Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring)